# Trying to learn python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 7 columns in my DataFrame, I'm trying to assign 0-5 and 7 variables as feature variables and I'm unable to get it. 
Here is the code I'm trying:

```
feature_vars = list(data_tab.domain.variables[:5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
feature_vars = data_tab.domain.variables[:5]+ data_tab.domain.variables[7]
```

i think that is what your trying to do how ever it seems like a very weird way to set it up. What you have written implies that you have an object called `'data_tab'` with and attribute `'domain'` with an attribute `'variables'` which is an array like object - f.x. a list.